# Node.js - Download File from Google Drive via request

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file from Google Drive using Node.js and the Request module.
I am getting the download link from the webContentLink area of the item metadata and these links work in my browser.

My request looks like this:

```
request.get({uri:item.webContentLink,headers:{authorization:'Bearer'+token}}).pipe(response);
```

My response is:

```
stream.js:79
dest.end();
     ^
TypeError: Object #<IncomingMessage> has no method 'end'
    at Request.onend (stream.js:79:10)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
```

I am using the method I found here https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/150

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit Full Code

```
var request = require('request');

//getting children of folder
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+id+"/children?maxResults=1000&q=trashed%3Dfalse&access_token="+token;;

request.get(url, function(err,response,body){

  detailsParse = JSON.parse(body);
  //if children are .mp3 then download

  if(detailsParse.mimeType == 'audio/mpeg'){
    var file = fs.createWriteStream("./"+detailsParse.title);

                    var getDown = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+detailsParse.id+"?access_token="+token;
                    request.get(getDown, function(err,response,body){
                        if(err){console.log(err)}

                        var downParse = JSON.parse(body);
                        request.get({uri:downParse.webContentLink,headers:{authorization:'Bearer'+token}}).pipe(response);
  }


})
```

Comment: What is `response` which you are piping to?

Comment: I was trying to pipe the response the I am receiving from the request to file.  

http://runnable.com/UmhMG6nlm5cPAAAd/download-a-file-with-request-for-node-js-and-webserver

This is another link where I thought this was possible.

Comment: Can you post the full code you are using?

Comment: I have added the full request I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the request response to the `pipe` instead of the file you created.

Change the code `.pipe(response);` to `.pipe(file);`

Comment: Thanks but when I do this I get a blank mp3 file.  The titles are correct but the files are empty.

Comment: just use `request(url).pipe` instead of `request.get(url).pipe`

Answer (score 4):

Okay this was wrong on a couple parts.
First @fmodos was correct in passing the results to 'file' the stream I had created before.

However this did not completely solve the problem because I was running into authentication issues and issues not using the correct endpoint so the full answer is below

```
var request = require('request');

//getting children of folder
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+id+"/children?maxResults=1000&q=trashed%3Dfalse&access_token="+token;

request.get(url, function(err,response,body){

  detailsParse = JSON.parse(body);
  //if children are .mp3 then download

  if(detailsParse.mimeType == 'audio/mpeg'){
    var file = fs.createWriteStream("./"+detailsParse.title);

    var getDown = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/"+detailsParse.id+"?access_token="+token;
    request.get(getDown, function(err,response,body){
      if(err){console.log(err)}

      var downParse = JSON.parse(body);
      //****THIS NEEDS TO BE THE downloadUrl ENDPOINT AND NOT THE webContentLink endpoint

      //*****NOTICE THE SPACE AFTER Bearer WAS MISSING BEFORE
      request.get({uri:downParse.downloadUrl,headers:{authorization:'Bearer '+token}}).pipe(response);
    });
  }


});
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your code! Im in a simular situation where you question and code helped me a bit further, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty old but I was just having issues with it, I've included an example of how I managed to get this working using the Google API Node.js library: https://gist.github.com/davestevens/6f376f220cc31b4a25cd